# Manga/Manhwa where the female lead is either transported into a novel/game she read before or or goes back in time on repeat

Tags: story-identification, comics, anime, manga

During the novel there's a scene where a male character tries to help her increase her power ability and during that, he has to snap her out of it because her ability is unlimited which is dangerous, her hair turns white during this scene. She had brown hair if I'm correct. This all happens at a school in the story too if that helps

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Was the story set in the modern world or centuries in the past? And can you tell us anything else about the plot, or any other characters?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[I'm No Heroine!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/im-no-heroine)*, aka *I Will Politely Decline the Male Lead!*.

> A girl obsessed with a novel suddenly finds herself transported into the thick of the plot. The problem is, she has taken on the role of the villain in the story. And she knows how this ends…it’s off with her head! Maybe she’ll just let this play out and wake up back in reality… But after a few too many deaths to no avail, it’s finally time to go off-script. She's going to have a little fun with this tale. She’s made up her mind…to live!

[image: Cover image]

The cover image shows her normally brown hair. The main character reincarnated in a book she read and decided to act out her role as a villainess. She dies at the end, as in the original story, but returned to the start of the story instead of returning to her own world. Then she dies again, and the comic takes place in her 3rd life within the story.

The scene with the white hair is in chapter 10. A mage from the tower is helping her tap into her magical potential for the first time in her three lives. It turns out that she has no restriction on the amount of her magic she could draw, while most people will stop before it causes physical problems.

[image: The magic training scene]